# How can I define a type in oracle11g that references a collection of that type?

Tags: database, oracle, object-relational-model

I want to do something like this

```
create type Item as object (
    id number,
    subitems table of ref Item
)
```

but oracle throws an exception when I try to do it. Is this possible, and if yes then how?

Comment: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "TABLE" when expecting one of t he following: <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-iden tifier> long double ref char time timestamp interval date binary national character nchar

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oracle will not compile your definition because the type `Item` hasn't been compiled yet.  Why dont you give this a try:

Compile this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Item;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE items_table IS TABLE OF REF item;
```

and then try:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE item AS OBJECT (
   id number,
   subitems items_table
)
```

Answer (score 0):

That would be nice wouldn't it! You could try this:

```
create type item_ids_t is table of number;

create type Item as object (
   id number,
   subitems item_ids_t);
```

Which means that subitems is just a list of ids, which would then be used to look up a table indexed by id.